# Laravel Blade OneToOne Undefined property

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

That's it, I try to make a OneToOne relationship (and even OneToMany) and then display the data with Blade.

So I have two entities: Test and Test2.

And it's Test that has the key test2_id.

But I have the error below when displaying lists

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$test2
```

Here are the codes:

Creation of the test table:

```js
<?php
 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
 
class CreateTestTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('test', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->integer('test2_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('test2_id')
 
                  ->references('id')
 
                  ->on('test2');
        });
    }
 
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('test');
    }
}
```

Creation of the test2 table:

```js
<?php
 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
 
class CreateTest2Table extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('test2', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('nameB', 100);
        });
    }
 
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('test2');
    }
}
```

The test model:

```js
<?php
 
namespace App;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Test extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'test';
 
    public $timestamps = false;
 
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'test2_id'];
 
    public function test2()
 
    {
 
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Test2');
 
    }
}
```

The Test2 model:

```js
<?php
 
namespace App;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Test2 extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'test2';
 
     public $timestamps = false;
 
     protected $fillable = ['nameB'];
 
     public function test()
 
{
 
    return $this->hasOne('App\Test');
 
}
}
```

The controller:

```js
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Test;
use App\Test2;
use App\Http\Requests\TestRequest;
 
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function getInfos()
 
    {
 
        return view('test_info');
 
    }
 
 
    public function postInfos(TestRequest $request)
 
    {
 
        $test2 = new Test2;
 
        $input = ['nameB' => 'monNomB'];
 
        $mtest2_id = $test2->create($input)->id;
 
        $test = new Test;
        $test->test2_id = $mtest2_id;
        $test->name = $request->input('name');
        $test->save();
 
        return redirect('listtest');
 
    }
 
 
    public function list(){
 
         
        $tests = \DB::table('test')->get();
 
        return view('test_ok', compact('tests'));
    }
 
}
```

And the file test_ok.blade:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OK</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>OK</h1>
@if(count($tests) > 0)
    @foreach($tests as $test)
        <p>Name: {{ $test->name }} - NameB: {{ $test->test2->nameB }}
    @endforeach
@endif
</body>
</html>
```

It is therefore in the display (in the file test_ok.blade) that I have the error message:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$test2
```

It's been several hours that I struggle like a devil but I can not find any solution.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your controller to use class properties.

```
public function list(){

    $tests = \App\Test::all();

    return view('test_ok', compact('tests'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use relationships when you are using `queryBuilder` in order to call relationship in your view you have to use `eloquent`

Change the below code:

```
public function list(){


        $tests = \DB::table('test')->get();

        return view('test_ok', compact('tests'));
    }
```

to

```
  public function list(){


        $tests = Test::all();

        return view('test_ok', compact('tests'));
    }
```

and now you'll be able to call relationship in your view,
to know more visit [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships).

Answer (score 0):

We are looking at two ways of accessing data from database in Laravel,

1. Query Builder
2. Eloquent ORM

From your sample code, it seems you are using Query Builder which will not let you take the full benefits of Eloquent ORM, like the one you are trying. Please change your code as bellow,

```
 public function list(){

    $tests =  Test::all();

    return view('test_ok', compact('tests'));
}
```

When you change the from Query builder to Eloquent ORM, your issue will be resolved.